# PALIN- The next Palindrome - a SPOJ problem

Tags: java

I have opened an account for Ridit, one of 7-years-old students learning Java at SPOJ. The first task i gave to him was PALIN -The Next Palindrome. Here is the link to this problem- [PALIN- The next Palindrome- SPOJ](https://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/)After i explained it to him, he was able to solve it mostly except removing the leading zeros, which i did. Following is his solution of the problem -

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int t = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            String[] numbersInString = new String[t];

            for (int i = 0; i <t; i++) {
                String str = in.nextLine();
                numbersInString[i] = removeLeadingZeros(str);
            }

            for (int i = 0 ; i<t; i++) {
                int K = Integer.parseInt(numbersInString[i]);
                int answer = findTheNextPalindrome(K);
                System.out.println(answer);

            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }
    static boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        String str = Integer.toString(x);
        int length = str.length();
        StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i = length - 1;i>=0;i--) {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);
            strBuff.append(ch);
        }
        String str1 = strBuff.toString();
        if(str.equals(str1)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    static int findTheNextPalindrome(int K) {
        for(int i = K+1;i<9999999; i++) {
            if(isPalindrome(i) == true) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }


    static String removeLeadingZeros(String str) {
        String retString = str;
        if(str.charAt(0) != '0') {
            return retString;
        }
        return removeLeadingZeros(str.substring(1));
    }

}
```

It is giving correct answer in Eclipse on his computer, but it is failing in SPOJ. If someone helps this little boy in his first submission, it will definitely make him very happy. I couldn't find any problem with this solution... Thank you in advance...

Comment: *failing in SPOJ* - for what input? or what's the error?

Comment: hmm. According to the comments below the tasks on the site it looks like several people have similar problems.

Comment: It seems to a SPOJ side error, can't see anything that would make it fail- what input are you using? Does it give you an error message?

Comment: To test it, i used boundary values like 00001, 999999 and some arbitrary values.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThenNextPallindrom2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int t = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
            t = sc.nextInt();
        }
        sc.nextLine();

        int[] arr, arr2;
        while(t > 0) {
            t--;
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            arr = getStringToNumArray(s);

            if(all9(arr)) {
                arr2 = new int[arr.length + 1];
                arr2[0] = 1;
                for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
                    arr2[i+1] = 0;
                }   
                arr2[arr2.length -1] = 1;
                arr = arr2;
            } else{
                int mid = arr.length/ 2;
                int left = mid-1;
                int right = arr.length % 2 == 1 ? mid + 1 : mid;
                boolean left_small = false;

                while(left >= 0 && arr[left] == arr[right]) {
                    left--;
                    right++;
                }

                if(left < 0 || arr[left] < arr[right]) left_small = true;

                if(!left_small) {

                    while(left >= 0) {
                        arr[right++] = arr[left--];
                    }

                } else {
                    mid = arr.length/ 2;
                    left = mid-1;
                    int carry = 1;

                    if(arr.length % 2 == 0) {
                        right = mid;
                    } else {
                        arr[mid] += carry;
                        carry = arr[mid]/10;
                        arr[mid] %= 10;
                        right = mid + 1;
                    }

                    while(left >= 0) {
                        arr[left] += carry;
                        carry = arr[left] / 10;
                        arr[left] %= 10;
                        arr[right++] = arr[left--];
                    }

                }

            }           
            printArray(arr);

        }

    }


    public static boolean all9(int[] arr) {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            if(arr[i] != 9)return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int[] getStringToNumArray(String s) {
        int[] arr = new int[s.length()];

        for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++) {                
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));  
        }

        return arr;

    }

}
```